# Lucene search is failing with Exception: ava.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine

Lucene's search is failing with exception after upgrading from Lucene 4.6 to 8.0 with the below error.

Exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected docvalues type NONE for field 'case.id' (expected one of [BINARY, SORTED]). Re-index with correct docvalues type.
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.checkField(DocValues.java:317)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocValues.getBinary(DocValues.java:352)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.join.DocValuesTermsCollector.lambda$binaryDocValues$0(DocValuesTermsCollector.java:48)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.join.DocValuesTermsCollector.doSetNextReader(DocValuesTermsCollector.java:44)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.SimpleCollector.getLeafCollector(SimpleCollector.java:33)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.join.GenericTermsCollector$2.getLeafCollector(GenericTermsCollector.java:128)
    at oracle.edq.casemanagement.search.cancel.CancellableCollector.collect(CancellableCollector.java:69)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  new SortedDocValuesField(fieldName, new BytesRef(value)); for feild which is throwing error message